# Read Array of Arrays

Tags: c#, .net

I have a block of C# that looks like this

```
    public static string[,] FileTypesDict = new string[,] {
            {"txt", "ReadFile"},
            {"doc", "ReadMSOfficeWordFile"},
            {"docx", "ReadMSOfficeWordFile"},
            {"xls", "ReadMSOfficeExcelFile"},
            {"xlsx", "ReadMSOfficeExcelFile"},
            {"pdf", "ReadPDFFile"},
    };
```

I would like to use this inside another function like this...

```
    static void FindFiles() {
        foreach (string type[] in FileTypesDict) {
            // Find all files with extension
            string[] files = Directory.GetFiles(FilePath, type[0]);
            // To be used in another fun way, the longer description
            string filetype = type[1]
        }
    }
```

That, of course, doesn't work... It seems to only work when I do this -->

```
    static void FindFiles() {
        foreach (string type in FileTypesDict) {
            Console.WriteLine(type);
        }
    }
```

That will print each part of each array, like this -->

```
txt
ReadFile
doc
ReadMSOfficeWordFile
docx
ReadMSOfficeWordFile
xls
ReadMSOfficeExcelFile
xlsx
ReadMSOfficeExcelFile
pdf
ReadPDFFile
```

I'd basically like to look over the array of arrays and use each array inside of the loop...

Comment: Is there any reason you're not using a `Dictionary<string,string>`?

Comment: `foreach (string[] type in FileTypesDict)` - does that fix it?

Comment: Please don't prefix your titles with ".Net C#" and such. That's what the tags are for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be using a `Dictionary` for this, as it makes things much neater and readable.

You could do this:

```
Dictionary<string, string> fileTypes = new Dictionary<string, string>()
{
    {"txt", "ReadFile"},
    {"doc", "ReadMSOfficeWordFile"},
    {"docx", "ReadMSOfficeWordFile"},
    {"xls", "ReadMSOfficeExcelFile"},
    {"xlsx", "ReadMSOfficeExcelFile"},
    {"pdf", "ReadPDFFile"}
};

foreach (KeyValuePair<string, string> file in fileTypes)
{
    Console.WriteLine(String.Format("{0} - {1}", file.Key, file.Value));
}
```

Or if you wanted to make the value a collection of string, you could do this:

```
   Dictionary<string, List<string>> fileTypesWithList = new Dictionary<string, List<string>>()
        {
            { "txt", new List<string>() { "Some", "Other", "Data" }}
        };

        foreach (KeyValuePair<string, List<string>> file in fileTypesWithList)
        {
            foreach (string s in file.Value)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(String.Format("{0} - {1}", file.Key, s));
            }

        }
```

Comment: Thanks for the example and better solution to what I was trying!

Comment: Finally got a chance to try this today. It took me a bit to realize I needed 'using System.Collections.Generic;' but after that it seemed to work perfect. :D

Answer (score 1):

The solution to your question is to define `FileTypesDict` as `string[][]`. Now I agree with the comments that the way you should do it is with a Dictionary.

Comment: Very simple resolution to what I was doing. I'll try to do the Dictionary instead since it's better. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

see here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2s05feca.aspx

```
    static void FindFiles()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < FileTypesDict.Length; i++)
        {
            var fileType = FileTypesDict[i, 0];
            var action = FileTypesDict[i, 1];

            string[] files = Directory.GetFiles(FilePath, fileType);
        }
    }
```